# Find closest timestamps between two dataframes and merge different columns when time difference is < 60s

Tags: r, merge, timestamp, closest

I need to merge two data frames based on the closest timestamp, with a maximum difference between timestamps of 60 seconds.

For example:

```
library(lubridate)

df1 <- data.frame(Timestamp = ymd_hms(c("2020-01-01 00:00:00", 
                                        "2020-01-01 00:02:00", 
                                        "2020-01-01 00:04:00",
                                        "2020-01-01 00:06:00", 
                                        "2020-01-01 00:08:00", 
                                        "2020-01-01 00:10:00",
                                        "2020-01-01 00:12:00",
                                        "2020-01-01 00:14:00", 
                                        "2020-01-01 00:16:00")), 
                  Data  = c(1:9))

df2 <- data.frame(Timestamp = ymd_hms(c("2020-01-01 00:00:10", 
                                        "2020-01-01 00:02:30", 
                                        "2020-01-01 00:12:45",
                                        "2020-01-01 00:20:15")), 
                  Data  = c(10:13))
```

There is continuous data taken at 2-minute intervals in `df1`.
There is sporadic data in `df2`.
The datasets do not have the same number of rows.

I need to merge `df1$Data` into a new column in `df2` (`df2$df1_Data`), but only where the time difference between `df1$Timestamp` and `df2$Timestamp` is less than 60 seconds.

Ideally the output would be:

```
>df2
            Timestamp   Data    df1_Data
1 2020-01-01 00:00:10   10      1
2 2020-01-01 00:02:30   11      2
3 2020-01-01 00:12:45   12      7
4 2020-01-01 00:20:15   13      NA
```

My R skills are not yet at a level where I can tackle this problem myself and I did not find something on this speficic question, would anyone be willing to hep? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be directly expressed in sql:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.*, b.Data df1_Data
  from df2 a
  left join df1 b on abs(a.Timestamp - b.Timestamp) < 60")
```

giving:

```
            Timestamp Data df1_Data
1 2019-12-31 19:00:10   10        1
2 2019-12-31 19:02:30   11        2
3 2019-12-31 19:12:45   12        7
4 2019-12-31 19:20:15   13       NA
```